# Are all the conditions of the Moore-Penrose inverse definitions necessary?

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

The Moore-Penrose inverse of a real or complex matrix $M$ is the unique matrix defined by four conditions. Can any of these four conditions be relaxed with no loss of uniqueness? I noticed there was a similar question to mine a while ago, but the question wasn't answered there.

Comment: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Existence_and_uniqueness) says no, but I don't know if the source of the reference [8] is accesible over internet to see if there is a proof.

Comment: By the way, there's a conceptual definition of the pseudoinverse of an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ (with entries in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$). The pseudoinverse of $A$, when viewed as a mapping, takes a vector $b$ as input and returns the least norm solution to $Ax = \hat b$, where $\hat b$ is the projection of $b$ onto the column space of $A$. To me this is by far the most clear definition of the pseudoinverse. All the various formulas for the pseudoinverse are consequences of this definition.

Comment: I'm a bit appalled that this most illuminating description of the pseudoinverse is buried halfway down the Wikipedia page in the "Geometric construction" section. It should be front and center, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0},B_1=\pmatrix{x&0\\ 0&0},B_2=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&x},B_3=\pmatrix{1&x\\ 0&0},B_4=B_3^T$ where $x$ is arbitrary. Then

- $B=B_1$ satisfies the conditions that $BAB=B$ and that $AB$ and $BA$ are Hermitian.
- $B=B_2$ satisfies the conditions that $ABA=A$ and that $AB$ and $BA$ are Hermitian.
- $B=B_3$ satisfies the conditions that $ABA=A,BAB=B$ and that $BA$ is Hermitian.
- $B=B_4$ satisfies the conditions that $ABA=A,BAB=B$ and that $AB$ is Hermitian.